# Strange app.js lifecycle and error handling in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have already searched all around stackoverflow and google but, since I am a beginner with NodeJs and Express, I'm trying to understand how the app.js lifecycle works.

Essentially I'm learning nodejs through a tutorial in which the app.js is implemented as follow

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//  db settings
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:27017/ucg'); //use db "ucg"

// get routers files
var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// get utility file
var utility = require('./lib/utility');
var utilityObj = new utility(); // since it's a class, it must be initialized     to use it

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico')); //uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// db settings: make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req, res, next){

console.log('standard request handler');

req.db = db;
next();
});

// set url paths to routers files to access them via browser
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next){

console.log('#404 handler');

var err = new Error('Not Found');
err.status = 404;
next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler: will print stacktrace
if(app.get('env') === 'development'){
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next){

    console.log('#dev error handler');

    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: err
    });
});
}

...

module.exports = app;
```

As you can see I have several components such as routers and error handlers but some console.log() calls have created a little bit of confusion.

When I do a simple request http://localhost:3000/ I've discovered some strange behaviours.

My questions is:
Why Does the app.js pass multiple times through some part of code, for example the "standard request handler"?
And why does it pass also through the error hanlder (which works fine when there is an error but in this case the request is ok)?
Should express use the right handler, depending on the parameter?

Probably I'm missing something.

```
standard request handler
[0mGET / [36m304 [0m393.870 ms - -[0m
[0mGET /stylesheets/style.css [36m304 [0m6.033 ms - -[0m
standard request handler
#404 handler
#dev error handler
[0mGET /javascripts/utility.js [33m404 [0m78.354 ms - 1404[0m
```

Thank you so much.

---

Update after the fix:

```
standard request handler
[0mGET / [36m304 [0m15.703 ms - -[0m
[0mGET /stylesheets/style.css [36m304 [0m1.987 ms - -[0m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the app.js pass multiple times through some part of code, for example the "standard request handler"?

The "standard request handler" is what Express calls [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html). These are functions that requests get passed through for some purpose (in your case, it is to set `req.db`). By calling `next()`, the middleware passes the request on to any following middleware and/or request handlers (there isn't really a distinction in Express between middleware and request handlers).

> And why does it pass also through the error handler (which works fine when there is an error but in this case the request is ok)?

Actually, the request *isn't* okay: a request is made for `javascripts/utility.js`, got passed through all the middleware and request handlers and none of those was able to handle the request (most likely because that path doesn't exist), so it ended up being "caught" by the "catch 404" handler, which generates an error that is subsequently passed to the error handler.

Comment: I didn't notice accurately all the GETs in the console. I have searched through the code and I have noticed that there were a old utility.js link that now is missed and a missing favicon. Now I have updated the log and the request lifecycle works smoothly. Very helpful!